# multi sockets in boost asio?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio

I wanted to make a chat server using boost::asio and as the program gets more complicated and difficult for myself to read, I was wondering if it is possible to use several sockets in the same client and on server side?

If I can't make myself quite clear to you, for example, in my server side I have `int` and `string` variables and I want to send them in different sockets NOT effecting to each other.

Well... `int` variable is sent through **socket1** and `string` is through **socket2.** The same thing with a client side that it should "know" from which socket `int` is "coming" and from which `string`. If this is possible I would be very glad to see some examples :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not at all sure what it is you are trying to do, but I'm pretty sure that, whatever it is, it's a really bad idea:(

Answer (score -1):

> the program gets more complicated and difficult for myself to read

You might want to refactor a bit. Even large code should be easy to read and understand.

> I have int and string variables and I want to send them in different sockets NOT effecting to each other.

You don't create a new socket for each data-type you want to send. Add a proper header to your message and parse the received data-type with error checking.

For instance (simplified case):

```
std::string tx = "12345678Test";

std::stringstream ss(tx);
int num;
ss >> num;

std::string s;
ss >> s;
```